# Pom/Jar file not in central location

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run an independent jar for my Java project which is running fine in IntelliJ.

The dependency [JRAW](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dean.jraw/JRAW/1.1.0) is included in my pom file but while running `mvn clean install` I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project reddit-crawl-maven: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test1:reddit-crawl-maven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.dean.jraw:JRAW:jar:1.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

It is mentioned [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dean.jraw/JRAW/1.1.0) that the jar file is present in [Spring Lib Release](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/net/dean/jraw/JRAW/1.1.0/).

How do I make my pom file look in the Spring library instaed of the maven central.

Also I am running `mvn -U clean install` to avoid the following error

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project reddit-crawl-maven: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test1:reddit-crawl-maven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find net.dean.jraw:JRAW:jar:1.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Alternate approaches:

1. It would even work if the local cached repository works since I want to make an independent JAR (platform independent).
2. If I could download the JRAW.JAR directly from source and compile maven accordingly.

Here is my pom file, if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>reddit-crawl-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.3</kotlin.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dean.jraw</groupId>
            <artifactId>JRAW</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>moshi</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!--<mainClass>com.test1.Main</mainClass>-->
                            <mainClass>event.handlers.InventoryEventHandler</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>com.test1.Main</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Did you configure that repository in your maven settings?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: See this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: It works after adding spring repository. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dean.jraw/JRAW/1.1.0), there's a note:

> Note: this artifact it located at **Spring Lib Release** repository
>   (http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/)

I think you need to declare this repository in your `pom.xml` as following:

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-lib-release-repo</id>
    <name>Spring Lib Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: do i also need to define maven central along with this, or is that always included by default?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Maven Central is defined by default.